# Make pdf open in new tab, embedded ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am having trouble getting a pdf to forcibly open in a new tab in an internal app.
This is the code that calls my component
`

```
  <%= render "shared/application_form/identity_document_summary",
             application_form: @assessment_section_view_object.application_form,
             changeable: false
             %>
```

`

This is the ERB component itself which gets a url for the file. The URL works correctly and the file opens, but the target attribute doesn't seem to work in the href attribute.

```
<%= render(CheckYourAnswersSummary::Component.new(
  id: "identity-document",
  model: application_form,
  title: I18n.t("application_form.tasks.items.identity_document"),
  fields: {
    identification_document: {
      title: "Identity documents",
      href: [:edit, :teacher_interface, :application_form, application_form.identification_document, target: :_blank],
    }, 
  },
  changeable:
)) %>
```

I have seen a few examples of similar questions on here using a 'link_to'. Should i refactor the code to use that instead of just a href?

Comment: Have you thought of changing this to a `send_data` and apply the `mime-attachment` type, to "download" the file, rather than embed it?

Comment: That did work, but more importantly made me realise that the problem was the component didn't know what to do with the attribute. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the component, since the component is separated out from the where the URL is generated, didn't know what to do with the target attribute.
I just moved the url in to the file, but I think this could also be done by having added the target attribute to where the url is generating from `application_form.identification_document`.